# react-select arrow key navigation for submenu

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, keyboard

I'm working on adding arrow key functionality to a react-select input dropdown with submenus. I am able to open the submenu, however I don't know how to be able focus an option from the submenu.

[image]

As you can see in the image, the submenu parent is selected. And I want to be able to focus the options on the right.

```
export const CustomOption = () => {
  const [showNestedOptions, setShowNestedOptions] = useState(false);
  const [subMenuOpen, setSubMenuOpen] = useState(null);

// this is used to give styling when an option is hovered over or chosen with arrow key
  const [isFocusedState, setIsFocusedState] = useState(false);

//  this basically opens the submenu on ArrowRight keyboard click and gives it isFocusedState(true) which is used to render the SELECTED submenu
  const handleKeys = (e: any) => {
    if (e.key === 'ArrowRight') {
      !props.isMobile && setShowNestedOptions(true);
      e.setIsFocusedState(true);
    } else if (e.key === 'ArrowLeft') {
      !props.isMobile && setShowNestedOptions(false);
      e.setIsFocusedState(false);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener('keydown', handleKeys);
    return () => {
      return window.removeEventListener('keydown', handleKeys);
    };
  }, []);

//  this does the same but on mouseOver (hover)
  const handleMouseOver = (e: any) => {
    !props.isMobile && setShowNestedOptions(true);
    setIsFocusedState(true);
  };

  const handleMouseLeave = (e: any) => {
    !props.isMobile && setShowNestedOptions(false);
    setIsFocusedState(false);
  };


  return (
    <Box>
      {props.data.nestedOptions ? (
        <Box
          onMouseLeave={handleMouseLeave}
          onMouseOver={handleMouseOver}
          onKeyDown={handleKeys}
          onClick={() => setIsFocusedState(!isFocusedState)}
        >
          <MainOption
            renderOption={props.renderOption}
            option={props.data}
            hasNestedOptions={true}
            setSubMenuOpen={() => setSubMenuOpen(props.data.value)}
            selectOption={selectOption}
            isFocused={isFocusedState}
          />
          {showNestedOptions && (
            <Box>
              {(isFocusedState || props.isFocused) &&
                map(props.data.nestedOptions, (nestedOption, index: number) => {
                  const isFirst = index === 0;
                  const value = props.getOptionValue?.(nestedOption) || props.value;
                  const label = props.getOptionLabel?.(nestedOption) || props.label;
                  const nestedInnerProps = innerProps;
                  nestedInnerProps.onClick = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) =>
                    selectOption(props.data.nestedOptions.find((o: SelectOption) => o.label === e.target.textContent));
                  const optionProps = {
                    ...props,
                    data: { ...nestedOption, parentValue: subMenuOpen },
                    value: value,
                    label: label,
                    children: label,
                    innerProps: { ...nestedInnerProps, parentValue: subMenuOpen },
                  };
// here the submenu is rendered and opened
                  return (
                    <Box
                      key={index}
                    >
                      <Option {...optionProps} key={value} isFocused={false}>
                        <Center>
                          {label}
                        </Center>
                      </Option>
                    </Box>
                  );
                })}
            </Box>
          )}
        </Box>
      ) : (
// if there's no submenu, simply render the list of options
        <Option {...props}>
          <MainOption
            isMobile={props.isMobile}
            option={props.data}
            getOptionValue={props.getOptionValue}
            renderOption={props.renderOption}
            wrapperOptionArg={props.wrapperOptionArg}
            getOptionLabel={props.getOptionLabel}
          />
        </Option>
      )}
    </Box>
  );
};
```

I have tried to add onKeyDown to change the isFocused prop conidtionally, like so but somehow it only works on mouseOver and it sets the condition inappropriately ( for all options, or none at all )

```
                  return (
                    <Box
                      key={index}
                    >
                      <Option 
                        {...optionProps} 
                        key={value} 
                        isFocused={props.data.nestedOptions[0] ? true : false} 
                        <Center>
                          {label}
                        </Center>
                      </Option>
                    </Box>
```

Unfortunately there's not much information about this certain keyboard functionality that I was able to find online.

In short, how to focus the first element of a submenu when ArrowRight is already used to open the submenu?